# Bloomberg Excel API: using ISIN and stock data missing

Tags: excel, function, bloomberg

I'm trying to download financial information (market and accountant information) for a long list of firm. I'm using the BDH function with the ISIN, and it works but only for accountant information. Instead for the market information such the volatility it give me "#ND /ND". But if I try to select manually the security with their name, istead of using the ISIN, Bloomberg give me the volatility I want. Why? What can I do?
This is a screenshot of my excel:

[image]

Where in the colum H I use the function

```
=BDH($C2;$I$1:$Z$1;$E2;$E2;"Quote=A";"Days=A";"Per=Y";"Dts=S")
```

Comment: It would help to give an example of values for C2, I1 and E2 that doesn't work. We don't even know what field you are querying.

Comment: C2 is the ISIN BLOOMBERG CODE, I1:z:1 are cells with the names of the variables I want from Bloomberg, and E2 is the start and the final date, they are the same because I want the data on the 31-12

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is due to a combination of using an ISIN (which is ambiguous because it refers to a company but not a specific listing) and `Per=Y`.

I suggest the following as a starting point:

- find the primary ticker using `=BDP(C2, "EQY_PRIM_SECURITY_TICKER")`
- find the primary exchange using `=BDP(C2, "EQY_PRIM_SECURITY_PRIM_EXCH")`
- concatenate the 2 to get a valid ticker: `=ticker & exchange & " Equity"`
- use this BDH formula: `=BDH(full_ticker, "VOLATILITY_30D", 20171231, 20171231, "Days=A,Fill=P,Dates=H")`

Comment: Thank you very much assylias, it worked. If I have also unlisted firm previously listed, how can I find the exchange?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: For example the Switzerland firm ACTELION is dead in the 2017, and obviously it is no longer listed, but was listed in the period 2002-2015, and if I use the function -->find the primary exchange using =BDP(C2,"EQY_PRIM_SECURITY_PRIM_EXCH") for this firm and other like this this function don't work. There is anoter function I can use?

Comment: @Jonny You can try other fields, such as `TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE` or `FUNDAMENTALS_TICKER`